# Best approach for multiple virtual Mac OS environments

Tags: macos, mac, virtualization

I'd like to test a piece of software against as many different versions of Mac OS as possible.

If I was to do this with Windows I could use something like VMware to install multiple versions on the one physical machine.

Is there a similar approach I can use to have multiple version of Mac OS on the same physical machine?

Answer (score 1):

For Mac OS, you have some virtualization products like "Parallels Desktop, VMware Fusion, or VirtualBox" which is specifically supported with Mac OS. This applications helps you to run multiple instance from same physical machine.

Hope this helps,